# how to highlight only first row of material table in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a material table in react. The code for styling is as follows:

```
                <MaterialTable 
                    options={
                        {
                            exportButton: true,
                            exportAllData: true,
                            pageSize: 5,
                            pageSizeOptions: [5, 10, 15],
                            paging: true,
                            actionsColumnIndex: -1,
                            rowStyle:rowData =>({
                                backgroundColor: rowData[0] ?? 'blue',
                            })
                        }
                    columns={
                        [
                        { align:'center',title: 'A', field: 'a'},
                        { align:'center',title: 'B', field: 'b'},
                        { align:'center',title: 'C', field: 'c'},
                        { align:'center',title: 'D', field: 'd'},
                    ]}
                    tableLayout='fixed'
                    data={tableData}
                        }
                    }
```

I want to highlight just the first row of the table. I tried to do that using rowStyle and rowData as shown on code but that just highlights all rows. How do I just highlight the first row of the table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change your `rowStyle` like this:

```
rowStyle: (data, rowData) => rowData === 0 && { background: "blue" }
```

or like this:

```
rowStyle: (data, rowData) =>
              data.tableData.id === 0 && { background: "blue" }
```

You decide which parameters is more convenient

Comment: that just highlights the header of the table, I'm looking to highlight the first row with data on the table

Answer (score 0):

I had similar requirement, In my case seleted row should be highlighted. For that have wrote styling condition based part of options property in the following way

```
<MaterialTable 
    onRowClick={useCallback((event, data) => setSelectedRow(data))}
    options={isEmpty(selectedRow) ? {
        exportButton: false,
        filtering: false,
        paging: false,
        search: true,
    } : {
        exportButton: false,
        filtering: false,
        paging: false,
        rowStyle: (data, rowData) => data.tableData.id === selectedRow?.tableData?.id && { background: '#1e88e5', color: 'white' },
        search: true,
    }}
    columns={[
        { field: 'shortName', title: 'Short Name' },
        { field: 'entityStatus.code', title: 'Status'},
    ]}
    data={lookUpClients}
    title={''}
/>
```